# Joomla 2.5 - Invalid Token (Random) when loading

Tags: web, joomla, content-management-system, jumi

sometimes my Joomla site doesn't load contents and i receive "Invalid Token" message. If i reload the webpage 3/4 times the site loads the contents normally but sometimes this method also doesn't work.

I'm using Joomla 2.5 and Jumi Plugin (for dynamic content in joomla article).

I have disabled joomla cache as written in other forum but the problem was not resolved.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Normally the token shouldn't be tested on pages which can be accessed from a menu.

You might have a plugin that checks for the token, as the content component doesn't it must be something else.

Turn on debug mode and see what modules / plugins are invoked. Did you disable the cache plugin as well? Clear the cache folder also to make sure it's not used.

Comment: Which are Cache folders?

Comment: /cache and /administrator/cache